# Selenium unable to find Log In button on the page using LINK_TEXT method

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to locate a "log in" button on a webpage and then to click it using the "LINK_TEXT" method, however it seems selenium is unable to locate this button for some reason:
Code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Log In"))).click()
except:
    print('exception occured')
    driver.quit()
time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
```

When I inspect element for the button in Chrome I can see the following:

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-red ng-binding" id="login-button" ng-click="onLoginClick($event)">Log In</button>
```

So I can see the link text is showing as "Log In" for this particular page so the LINK_TEXT method should've detected this but isn't.

Any ideas?

Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on `Log In` button use any of the below `locator strategy`.

**XPath:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Log In']"))).click()
```

**CSS selector:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#login-button"))).click()
```

**ID:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "login-button"))).click()
```

Comment: The XPATH method worked now but I'm wondering why is it that the ID method or the LINK_TEXT method doesn't work. It seems really inconsistent which is a big headache when it comes to programming.

Comment: @mya205 : It should work with ID as well, However LINK_TEXT works with <a> tag.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in selenium but I do know Angular and the Log In button may be affected by the angular framework behind it and in this case, I would replace

```
(By.LINK_TEXT, "Log In")
with
(By.Id, "login-button")
```

I'm not a 100% sure this will work but I'd give it a try. Let me know if it works!

Comment: No errors are thrown with this approach but the "Log In" button itself isn't actually being pressed using this method.

Comment: This is using Python, Xpath is another language?

Comment: @mya205 you can use By.XPATH in selenium and then use the xpath of the login button as the second parameter.

Comment: I just noticed but, if the button isn't initially disabled, you should use EC.presence_of_element_located()

Comment: Sorry I'm really confused about what xpath is, right now I'm using this:

Comment: "EC.element_to_be_clickable" so the program would wait until it was clickable so I'm not sure if the "element_located" option would be much different

Answer (score 0):

Let's see an alternative approach...
How about not clicking 'Log in" button, but instead hit enter after .send_keys(password)??

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

(... some code ...)

driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```